# ansible obtain values from changing key

Tags: json, ansible

I would like to  get value from json, but one of the key can be differet.

here is example json

```
{
"json": {

    "id": "9758b1e5-442e-4545-9364-45f28477edfb",
    "results": [{
        "code": 200,
        "host": "localhost",
        "message": "no change",
        "runTime": 1233,
        "tenant": "http-validate-2.usa-dc.com"
    }],
    "traces": {
        "http-validate-2.usa-dc.comCurrent": {
            "/Common/10.10.100.10": {
                "command": "ltm node"

            },


            "http-validate-2.usa-dc.comDiff": [{
                "command": "ltm virtual",
                "kind": "D",
                "lhs": {
                    "default": "yes"
                },
                "lhsCommand": "ltm virtual",
                "path": [
                    "/http-validate-2.usa-dc.com/app/vs_http-validate-2.usa-dc.com_80",
                    "properties",
                    "persist",
                    "/Common/cookie"
                ],
                "rhsCommand": "ltm virtual",
                "tags": [
                    "tmsh"
                ]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

}

my ansible playbook

```
tasks:
 

 - name : deploy json file AS3  to F5
   debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('file', 'parse.json') }}"
   register: atc_AS3_status

    
 - name: debug
   debug:
     msg: "{{ atc_AS3_status.msg.json['traces']['.*Diff']}}"
```

I would like to reach key "path"   but the key above "http-validate-2.usa-dc.comDiff" can be different like "http-validate-3.can-dc.comDiff"  but always finish with Diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *json_query*, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ json.traces|json_query('*.*[][].path') }}"
```

should give the list of the paths (there might be more of them)

```yaml
  msg:
  - - /http-validate-2.usa-dc.com/app/vs_http-validate-2.usa-dc.com_80
    - properties
    - persist
    - /Common/cookie
```

---

Q: **"*I need path only in the key which ends Diff.*"**

A: [JMESPath](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is not able to search key wildcards, AFAIK. Instead, use *select* and create the list of the nested keys that match the regex, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ json.traces|json_query('*.keys(@)')|flatten|
                 select('match', '^.*Diff$')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - http-validate-2.usa-dc.comDiff
```

Then iterate this list, select *path* and concatenate the list *paths*, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        paths: "{{ paths|d([]) + json.traces|json_query(query) }}"
      loop: "{{ json.traces|json_query('*.keys(@)')|flatten|
                select('match', '^.*Diff$')|list }}"
      vars:
        query: '*."{{ item }}"[].path'
```

gives the list of paths for the keys that match the regex

```yaml
  paths:
  - - /http-validate-2.usa-dc.com/app/vs_http-validate-2.usa-dc.com_80
    - properties
    - persist
    - /Common/cookie
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thank you ,but as you wrote there might be more paht in different key and I need path only in key which end Diff. Do you know how to do it ?